# Raspberry Pi touch screen button on click sends data to database

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi3, touchscreen, windows-iot-core-10

I am using the codes from the site (https://www.hackster.io/dotMorten/windowsiottouch-44af19)
 to display my touchscreen.

Every sqlite code i tried doesnt work. 
I cant even use reference :'using microsoft.data'

I cant connect my UWP to database.I followed many tutorials and tried the nuget package also but it doesnt work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using TouchPanels.Devices;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Peers;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Provider;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using SQLite;
using SQLitePCL;



// The Blank Page item template is documented at 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace WindowsIoT.TouchSample
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a 
Frame.
/// </summary>
/// 
public sealed partial class ManualUnlock : Page
{
    //Please help change the database constring
    // string connStr = @"Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;" +"Initial 
       Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True;";
    //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    //conn.Open();
    private SQLiteConnection sql_con;
    private SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;


    const string CalibrationFilename = "TSC2046";
    private Tsc2046 tsc2046;
    private TouchPanels.TouchProcessor processor;
    private Point lastPosition = new Point(double.NaN, double.NaN);
    public ManualUnlock()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void page_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        //write logic here
        string tempcode = NumGen();
        txtOTP.Text = tempcode;

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        while (timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 120)
        {
            using (sql_con)
            {
                // create a new database connection:
                SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn =
                  new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=App_Data/Simplicity.mdf;");
                // open the connection:
       ******************  sqlite_conn.Open();  
                sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE OTP =@otp";
                // The SQLiteDataReader allows us to run through each row per loop
                while (sqlite_datareader.Read()) // Read() returns true if there is still a result line to read
                {
                    // Print out the content of the text field:


                    /*Sends message to database saying authenticated*/

                }
            }
        }
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

red lines from "open" on asterisk line although i have reference

Comment: Please try to forget what you know. Then read this question. Would you know how to help? Please check this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and come back to edit your question into a more useful question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine. Unlike most other SQL databases, SQLite does not have a separate server process. SQLite reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files.From the code you provided,

> SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=App_Data/Simplicity.mdf;");

It seems that the database is not SQLite but SQL Server database file.You can refer to this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sqlite-Sample-for-Windows-ad3af7ae) about Sqlite support in Windows 10 UWP, or you can refer to this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) that shows how to use SQLite to store and retrieve data in a light-weight database on the your device.

Comment: Hi sir, Thanks for clarifying.I really am blur in this field. If I have a background application and now I want to call it to run forever as long as my app is running, How do i implement it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/trigger-background-task-from-app                                              Do I trigger it?or is there a way i can force the background task called "startuptask.cs" to run in the background while the XAML has buttons that trigger other events that require user interaction?

Comment: Windows 10 IoT Core supports headed and headless apps.You can set headless app as a 'Startup App', the app will be started while device boot.You can refer to [Developing Background Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications).

Comment: OH..Thank you. I kinda felt stupid realising that I could have done that in the first place>.<